# GlobalScope.launch doesn't finish its task inside runBlocking main function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, terminate, file-writing, global-scope

I don't understand why in the program below `GlobalScope.launch` instruction doesn't finish its task.

I do understand that `runBlocking` has no control over `GlobalScope` and it's usually bad to use it, but that doesn't make me know why instructions inside `GlobalScope.launch {}` doesn't execute as expected.

The code snippet:

```kotlin
package coroutines

import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import java.io.File

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val file = File(javaClass.getResource("/coroutines_file.txt").path)

        file.printWriter().use { out ->
            repeat(10) { i ->
                delay(100)
                out.println(i.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output inside coroutines_file:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Actual output:

*An empty file.*

Comment: [Global coroutines are like daemon threads](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#global-coroutines-are-like-daemon-threads). `.join()` it if you want to wait for its completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GlobalScope` is just an escape hatch from structured concurrency. It can't be cancelled, it doesn't even have a `Job` associated with it, so it doesn't offer a top-level facility that tracks all the jobs launched inside it.

On the other hand, `runBlocking` establishes its own scope that you should inherit for the launched coroutine, and it automatically ensures all the child coroutines run to completion.

```kotlin
runBlocking<Unit> {
    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val file = File(javaClass.getResource("/coroutines_file.txt").path)
        file.printWriter().use { out ->
            repeat(10) { i ->
                delay(100)
                out.println(i.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does kill the GlobalScope process and why? I'm pretty new to JVM world. I don't understand why the program stops, even tho there is a job to do i.e. instructions inside GlobalScope.launch, and it wasn't finished nor told to stop.

Comment: Coroutine scope is not a process, it is just an object holding a `CoroutineContext`, and Kotlin makes it easy to pass the scope object down the coroutine hirerarchy. Specifically, `GlobalScope` defines a completely empty `CoroutineContext`, so you end up using the `Default` coroutine dispatcher. This maps to the JVM's global threadpool, `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`, and that one uses threads marked as "daemon" which in Java means that it gets automatically killed when all non-daemon threads have ended.

Comment: Oh, now I get it! Thank you a lot!

Comment: "there's no facility in it to await the completion of jobs launched inside it" is a bit confusing. It sounds like one can't even `.join()` the `Job`s `launch`ed inside `GlobalScope`.